# What does this clojure expression do (taken from O'Reilly book)

Tags: clojure, maps

I'm new in Clojure Programming. Have been playing with it for a week now. I read the book **"Clojure Programming"** and after reading again and again and try to dissect this function in REPL but don't know how exactly this function works:

```
(defn reduce-by [key-fn f init coll]
  (reduce (fn [summaries x]
        (let [k (key-fn x)]
          (assoc summaries k (f (summaries k init) x))))
      {} coll))
```

I am still cannot understand the `assoc` part:

```
(assoc summaries k (f (summaries k init) x))))
```

Especially in the `(summaries k init)`. It doesn't look like a function because `summaries` is defined as a map.

The function is intended to be used as follows

```
(def orders
    [{:product "Clock", :customer "Wile Coyote", :qty 6, :total 300}
     {:product "Dynamite", :customer "Wile Coyote", :qty 20, :total 5000}
     {:product "Shotgun", :customer "Elmer Fudd", :qty 2, :total 800}
     {:product "Shells", :customer "Elmer Fudd", :qty 4, :total 100}
     {:product "Hole", :customer "Wile Coyote", :qty 1, :total 1000} 
     {:product "Anvil", :customer "Elmer Fudd", :qty 2, :total 300}
     {:product "Anvil", :customer "Wile Coyote", :qty 6, :total 900}])

(reduce-by :customer #(+ %1 (:total %2)) 0 orders)
```

and it will yield a seq like below

```
;= {"Elmer Fudd" 1200, "Wile Coyote" 7200}
```

I appreciate to anyone who can explain it to me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, looks like I figured it out.

Because maps are also functions, `(summaries k init)`  will return the value of `init` if the map `summaries` doesn't contain key `k`.

Silly me to skim and forget.

Comment: If you found the answer yourself, just mark your own answer as accepted. Please don't add the word *closed* to the question title.

Comment: Thanks Dominic, but it says I could only accept my own answer tomorrow.